# Posting issues more common while on VPN?

Tags: discussion

So often when I post I get "An error occurred during submission." Resubmitting doesn't help and I am forced to refresh the page. At that point, I have to verify that I am human.

What happened to this site? I've been patiently waiting for months, maybe a year it to get better but I see no signs of improvement.

It can't be just me, because I have this issue across multiple browsers and  multiple PCs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Note that this Question ironically went in without an error.

Comment: I have never seen this.  Perhaps you have a dodgy connection?

Comment: Maybe a year, but you're *just now* reporting a problem? You're very patient...

Comment: I've seen this many times while using mobile phone / tablet with bad 3G connection..

Comment: I've never seen this on a proper DSL line.

Comment: Whenever I refresh the page I'm always asked to verify that I am human. So I've stopped doing that.

Comment: Yep, -2 for speaking the truth about a sacred cow.

Comment: Refreshing was the only way to clear the error.

Comment: I've worked at 3 companies in the last year with stable fast networks and access this site from multiple browsers on multiple  including from home. The problems occur in every site.

Comment: I am not patient. I'm just cynical\realistic of the outcome of reporting it.

Comment: "The truth about a sacred cow" suggests that other users are experiencing the same problems, but not speaking out because of their blind allegiance to the site and downvoting to censor you. That's a pretty ridiculous suggestion when you look at the stuff that gets asked on Meta. People will complain about the naming of fracking *CSS classes*, for God's sake. And any downtime, no matter how short, will result in five "why is Stack Overflow not reachable?" bug reports

Comment: I think you could have a valid question here (especially given one of your answers) if you consider rewriting the title and providing more details--which browsers? Operating systems?

Comment: Multiple PCs (3 different laptops) and I have a desktop at home. What blows my mind is that you guys aren't saying "yeah, me too!"

Comment: I have seen this many times. I never reported it because it is random and resolves itself quickly.

Comment: As mentioned in another comment. I'm thinking that the common thread is VPN. I've used both Nortel and Cisco and definitely had this issue. I will monitor my home PC which is certainly more reliable at least.

Comment: I've been browsing SO for almost a year now and never run into this problem. What OS & Broswer Versions are you running? what plugins are you running?

Comment: IE 8.0.6 and Chrome 20.0 on Windows XP SP2. One common add-in across all jobs is the Code Library utility, which I love. I doubt that it is it. I will disable and monitor.

Comment: @Bluefeet: Were you on VPN when it occured?

Comment: no, I have had this happen without VPN.

Answer (score 11):

Looking at the traffic logs...

We've got no recorded errors (500s, and so on) from your account (or IPs your account has used) in the last 48 hours.  I only see a handful of 404s, and they look legit (GET-ing POST-only routes or global auth denials [which are normal]).

That style error message will popup when an ajax request times out or otherwise fails to complete, it can be the result of a purely client side error.

If you want to try and capture what's actually failing when you're experiencing this problem (Fiddler, Chrome networking tab, whatever) we can take another look, but based on the data I've got on hand it looks like something network related is mucking things up on your end.

Comment: Trying to test while using Chrome Networking tab. Edit: It's working.

Comment: Test #2. Trying o see if I can get an error again. Before it was happening right and left/

Comment: No luck. It works now.

Comment: I am trying to use the network tab of Chrome. It seems that the longer it takes before I commit a comment, the more likely the error occurs. I had the Chrome Network tab up a moment ago when I got the error. It was something showing a redirect from a company server. I tried to click to see if I could get more info, and I lost even that msg. This is the first time I am running it. I'll commit this is a min or two & prob get an error.

Comment: Unexpected response code: 302 :1
POST http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/392156/edit 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min.js:4
POST http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/392156/edit 409 (Conflict)

Comment: If I wait too long, I get an error that a comment can only be open for 5 mins. This is the first time that I ever waited THAT long. I don't consider this a system issue, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there could be `[Retry]` link within some error boxes, when clicked it could try to resubmit request. I'm not sure if it's worth it if reclicking `add comment` (*or like*) button already does same request again.

[image: Retry link in error box]

How about it? Can it work without wasting resources for example if post is being migrated or deleted while trying to post comments?

Comment: I kid you not. I just closed Chrome and opened IE and tried to post a comment reply. The comment appeared to have been submitted w/o error but no comment appeared. ppoof. gone. This is anotehr common issue. It gets to the point where before I submit I put my post on my clipbaord.

Comment: @user145973 It seems that this would not give solution for your problem (_[if your connection is stable](http://www.dslreports.com/tools)_). There's something else going on. However this could help mobility users and users with unstable connection.

Comment: Interesting theory about the realiability of the connection. However, as I noted, of my 3 employers in te last year and my home, none of the connections appear to be "stable" enough for SO to work reliably. Yet, my general browsing is without incident. I think it's a pretty safe bet that for every one person who reports an issue there are scores that just live with it.

Comment: This is a test post from my Desktop. Previous posts for this thread were from my work laptop while on VPN.

Comment: I mostly post from my work laptops, that all run Notel VPN client (and now Cisco). I believe that I also have issues from my personal PC but I mostly post from my work PCs. I will monitor it.

Comment: Wow, I thought I answered that question but that must've been a lost post. At my current job, I am running Windows XP SP2 with Chrome 20 and IE 8. My previous jobs all used Win XP too, and various versions of Chrome and IE. Since I switched to my personal Windows 7 PC my posts have been trouble free. I run no addins.

Comment: Corrction. Add-Ins displayed in image. I will disable all but Java. I have been using Code Library for years. I hope that's not it.

Comment: @user145973 Does your whole internet go through VPN? If it goes then there probably is other mangles too on route before reaching SO. I mean all those firewalls and sb routers (_had problems with them in past_)... Maybe you could try to do some stress testing with your connection. You should [edit your post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/139081/edit) and include all information you provided here as comments to my post.

Comment: I believe it does, because I cannot connect to teh Internet without 1st establishing a VPN conenction, though this wasnt the casse with my previous laptops from earlier employers.

Comment: @user145973 it's almost certainly an issue of the VPN being inbetween. You could talk to the IT department about configuring it such that your computer does not use the "default gateway on [the] remote network" (that's the Advanced TCP/IP settings name in Windows UI) to see if that alleviates this issue.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion to go through the corporate bureaucracy so all users within my company could access SO problem-free. That wouldn't help the users at my last two companies or (presumably) other companies. But I would think that the owners of the SO Exchange Q&A web app would want to fix it.